# SwiftUI Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type “ ” found

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am having the following fatal error:

> SwiftUI Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type “ ” found and @EnvironmentObject error: may be missing as an ancestor of this view」 is occured.

Xcode version:

> Xcode:12.1 and Core Bluetooth

My codes are as bellow:

ble.swift

```
import CoreBluetooth

・・・

class BLEConnection:NSObject, CBPeripheralDelegate,CBCentralManagerDelegate,ObservableObject 
{
　@EnvironmentObject var GS: GlobalStatus

　・・・・
  
  func startCentralManager()
  {
    //Process of start BLE Scan
  }

  public func centralManager(・・・) ←　Scanned Peripheral
  {
    let localName:String
   
    if(localName == GS.beaconid)　　←　★★★Fatal Error Occured this point.★★★
    {
　     ・・・・
    }
  ・・・・
```

GlobalStatus.swift

```
class GlobalStatus: ObservableObject
{
  @Published var beaconid = "ID001"
}
```

ProjectName.swift

```
@main
struct ProjectName: App
{
  let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared
  
  var body: some Scene
  {
     WindowGroup
     {
       ContentView()
       .environment(\.managedObjectContext,persistenceController.container.viewContext)
       .environmentObject(GlobalStatus())   
     }  
  }
}
```

ContentView.swift

```
・・・
struct ContentView: View
{
  @ObservedObject var bke = BLEConnection()
  
  var body: some VIew
  {
    NavigationView
    {
       Text("Test")
    }.onAppear(perform: ble.startCentralManager)
  }
}
```

How can I resolve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`@EnvironmentObject` is for SwiftUI view. In class just use regular property:

```
class BLEConnection:NSObject, CBPeripheralDelegate,CBCentralManagerDelegate,ObservableObject 
{
　var GS: GlobalStatus!
 
 // ...
}
```

and in your view just inject one into another (as one of approach)

```
struct ContentView: View
{
　@EnvironmentObject var GS: GlobalStatus
  @ObservedObject var bke = BLEConnection()
  
  var body: some VIew
  {
    NavigationView
    {
       Text("Test")
    }.onAppear {
       ble.GS = self.GS
       ble.startCentralManager()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem was solved by fixing the sorce according to the answer.
Thanks a lot.